# Siebel 7.8.2.16 on Windows 8/IE10

Tags: oracle, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, siebel

Does anyone know if Siebel 7.8 is supported on IE10 and above? One application is about to be sunset, but will continue for a few months, but the desktops will be upgraded to Windows 8.

Any link to sources from Oracle for supporting or not supporting IE10 will be appreciated, since the official docs (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11886_01/siebel/books/SRSP78/SRSP78.pdf) do not talk about Windows 8 support

Answer (score 0):

The last supported platform for High Interactivity mode is Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 8 (that is mentioned in document you are linked to the question). As far as I know there is no option to use Windows 8 with IE8, so the plain answer is: no, you cannot use it to access Siebel applications. Still if you find a way to install IE8 there is a little chance that it will work. Consider using some type of virtualization (Windows 8 Pro includes HyperX VM software) or any other methods.

Comment: I personally came across several problems with IE9 and Siebel 8.0. Cannot say anything about 7.8, but presume that situation should be pretty similar. Mainly it works, but there are glitches here and there. The biggest flaw is that Oracle doesn't support that browser version officially, so any issue or SR will be rejected by support. Therefore my opinion is not to use any IE version higher than 8.